# Insertar datos en un array y devolver la mitad sin que se repitan los valores

Tags: java, array

Tengo que llenar un array de [20] y de esos 20 valores mostrar 10 en pantalla
los cuales no sean repetidos.

Los valores que van dentro del array deben ser introducidos por el usuario y debo mostrarle al usuario 10 de esos 20 sin que ninguno de los 10 se repita.

Alguien puede ayudarme ?

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a SOes. Aquí no se hacen tareas, se resuelven dudas puntuales y para eso necesitamos ver lo que has intentado. Te recomiendo echar un vistazo a [ask], hacer el [tour] y aprender a hacer un [mcve]

Answer (score -1):

Mira a ver si te vale esto, lo malo es que los inicializa a -1 en el segundo vector, por eso si los numeros introducidos diferentes son menores del tamaño del segundo array te muestra los -1, esto se prodia solucionar con un bucle for que cuente los distintos de -1 y los introduzca en un nuevo array con la longitud del contador.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Numeros {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] vector, vectorDistintos;
    vector = new int[20];
    vectorDistintos = new int[10];
    boolean igual;
    int contador=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
        vector[i] = teclado.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("");
    for (int i = 0; i < vectorDistintos.length; i++) {
        vectorDistintos[i] = -1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < vector.length && vectorDistintos[vectorDistintos.length-1]==-1; i++) {
        igual = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < vectorDistintos.length; j++) {
            if (vector[i] == vectorDistintos[j]) {
                igual = true;
            }
        }
        if (!igual) {
            vectorDistintos[contador]=vector[i];
            contador++;
        }
    }


    System.out.println("VECTOR");
    for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(vector[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("VECTOR 2");
    for (int i = 0; i < vectorDistintos.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(vectorDistintos[i]);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Hola, teniendo en cuenta que el usuario no añadido ninguna información relevante a su pregunta, como algún ejemplo, lo que ha probado, errores, etc...., se desaconseja contestar la pregunta ya que se fomementan preguntas de baja calidad.